# Deceptive site ahead on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have azure blob storage, which contain only public images. 
I use URLs of images in my apps. Everything works fine for long time.

From yesterday I start getting **Deceptive site ahead** red error window on Chrome on Blob Storage URL and for all my images.

Any idea what can be a reason?

Comment: May you can refer to some helpful issues like https://yogeshkhetani.com/deceptive-site-ahead-google-chrome-error/ that will helps.

Comment: Thanks @PeterPan for good article, I already tried Report Google a Detection Problem without success. And having this kind of problem on azure storage that only contains images, does not make any sense.

Comment: Only on Chrome? Do you try to use other browsers like Firefox or MS Edge? And is there other more information to help fixing it, such as the information of the image url in the tab `Network` of Chrome devtool?

Comment: On MS Edge works fine but Firefox also giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just per my experience, I think the issue is not caused by your images on Azure Blob Storage or the self of Azure Storage.

Possibly with Chrome update, your current account of Azure Storage may be added into some filter list of danger website by someone. Please try to use the older version of Chrome or Firefox or other browsers like Brave or Vivaldi or Yandex to test again to check whether the reason is.

Otherwise, you can try to create a new account of Azure Storage to store some same images to test in your Chrome. If not, you need to report the issue to Google or Mozilla to ask for removing the mistake for your website.